# Critical process check at WDK development

Tags: c++, windows, driver, wdk

I have been searching information on process info. I would like to know whether 
a process is critical one or not. I have already done it within the application layer. However, I cannot judge whether a process is critical at the Driver layer(kernal)

I need to know whether a process is critical
so that I do not kill a critical process to avoid windows crash.

Can you help me on this issue?

Lots of love,

Comment: At the driver level there are no processes, and you cannot ‘kill’ a driver.

Comment: Actually, this driver checks windows processes, and kills some of them if they are suspicious of trojan attacks, or any other malicious behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on doing the check from the kernel, you can use ZwQueryInformationProcess with the BreakOnTermination class.

You can also use two-way IPC to communicate with a Windows service which will perform the check for you.